# Apache Ant Ivy fails to publish artifact to Artifactory

Tags: ant, jenkins, ivy, artifactory

I'm using Jenkins as the CI server, and Apache Ivy is used to manage the dependencies of the Android project, and Artifactory is the repository hosting all artifacts.

In the ivysettings.xml, configuration looks like below :

```
  <ibiblio name="test" m2compatible="true" 
    root="http://ip:8888/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local" 
    pattern="[organisation]/[module]/1.0/[artifact]-**1.0**-SNAPSHOT.[ext]">
  </ibiblio>
```

When building in Jenkins, I hit an error :

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\.jenkins\workspace\test\build.xml:1381: impossible to publish artifacts for com.test#dummy;working@myserver: java.io.IOException: PUT operation to URL http://ip:8888/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/test/dummy/1.0/project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.apk failed with status code 500: Failed to save resource 'libs-snapshot-local:com/test/dummy/1.0/project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.apk'.
    at org.apache.ivy.util.url.AbstractURLHandler.validatePutStatusCode(AbstractURLHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.upload(BasicURLHandler.java:225)
    at org.apache.ivy.util.url.URLHandlerDispatcher.upload(URLHandlerDispatcher.java:82)
    at org.apache.ivy.util.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:148)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLRepository.put(URLRepository.java:84)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.AbstractRepository.put(AbstractRepository.java:130)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.put(RepositoryResolver.java:234)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.publish(RepositoryResolver.java:216)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ChainResolver.publish(ChainResolver.java:244)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.publish.PublishEngine.publish(PublishEngine.java:281)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.publish.PublishEngine.publish(PublishEngine.java:260)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.publish.PublishEngine.publish(PublishEngine.java:172)
    at org.apache.ivy.Ivy.publish(Ivy.java:600)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyPublish.doExecute(IvyPublish.java:311)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.execute(IvyTask.java:277)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 9 seconds
Finished: FAILURE
```

However, when I change the highlighted '**1.0**' to '1', it's published to Artifactory successfully. It looks like dot '.' is not allowed. Or anything I did is wrong?

Please advise.

Comment: Can you check if Artifactory's log contains any errors/exceptions and post them?

Comment: Another thing I've noticed is that you're deploying the artifact to a supposedly m2 compatible repository but reviewing the deployment path, it doesn't seem to comply to the Maven 2 standard for a number of reasons.

Comment: Hi noamt, could you please explain more about why it doesn't comply to m2 standard? The Artifactory log just contains one line of 500 error code, and no detailed error there.

Comment: For one, Maven has no concept of OMRC (org, module, revision, classifier) and artifact, but GAVC (groupId, artifactId, version and classifier). Note that Ivy's module and artifact may differ. A general Maven pattern looks like "[groupId]/[artifactId]/[version]/[artifactId]-[version]-([classifier]).[ext]". Your pattern doesn't comply since the artifact ID isn't part of the path, and the versions in within the path and file name differ.

Comment: A 500 response is quite severe and it's quite strange that you don't see a more detailed error; It may also help if you can post to github an example test project that reproduces it consistently.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not even sure why you could publish with ibiblio, it supposedly only handles dependency resolution. See: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/ibiblio.html

you need a url resolver to handle publish, and define the pattern properly
http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/url.html

e.g.

```
<url name="test" m2compatible="true" 
  <ivy pattern="http://ip:8888/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml" />
  <artifact pattern="http://ip:8888/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
</url>
```

looks like you hardcoded the version, maybe try with the [revision] token